# Loop through textFields ONLY, in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, for-loop

I have a custom `UITableView`. I have `textFields` and other objects in the `tableView`. I'm trying to loop through all the `textFields` **only**.

Here is my Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.rowArray count]; i++) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
    for (UITextField *textField in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
    }
}
```

The app crashes with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89eb57b000'
```

The problem is obviously that it cannot do an `NSLog` of an image. But it wasn't supposed to. It was just supposed to go through the `textFields`?

Comment: with iOS version you used?

Comment: replace this line `for (uiView *view in [cell subviews]) {
if([view isKindOfClass [UITextFields class] ])

        NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
    
}`

Comment: Do you mean, `view.text`? there is no `.text` in `UIView`

Comment: yes replace  textField.text to view.text it work

Comment: it is good enough to worry about the _visible cells_ only, you don't need to iterate through the rest 10,000 non-existing cells if you have 4 visible only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the *class* of the subviews using [`isKindOfClass:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:):

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.rowArray count]; i++) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
    for (id subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
       if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
           UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subview;
           NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
       }
    }
}
```

**NOTE** You should not be interrogating the tableview in this way as it's the *V* bit of *MVC* and you already have access to all the data within the *M* bit...

Comment: So what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @MikeRally See my edit.  You should already have easy access to the data from with the *model* (the data you populate the tableview from via its datasource methods).

Comment: The tableView is linked to a custom cell class. So how would I pass the data?

Comment: @MikeRally The question is: How are you populating the tableview?

Comment: I populate it in the storyboard, then link the properties to `customCell.m`

Comment: So you have methods that feed data into the tableview.  Therefore why do you need to get the data out again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72302/discussion-between-mike-rally-and-trojanfoe).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Provide a unique tag to the textField when u add them as subview to the cells.  For Example: Take a constant value

```
#define  kTagTextField   1211
```

Now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`  do this

```
[textField setTag:(kTagTextField+indexPath.row)];
```

and where u want to have the text do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.rowArray count]; i++) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
    if([cell viewWithTag:(kTagTextField+i)]) { 
       UITextField *txtField = [cell viewWithTag:(kTagTextField+i)];
       NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this better than using `isKindOfClass`?

Comment: Both ways are correct. You can opt the one you want.

Comment: Which way requires more effort and is more error-prone (i.e. forgetting to set the tag)?

Comment: I'd probably go with `isKindOfClass:` as this could have all sorts of errors it's self. What if you give lets say a `UIImageView` the same tag? It will get into your if statement. Definitely go with `isKindOfClass:`

Comment: @trojanfoe your way of doing is better than mine. Even I got something to learn. Thanks a tonne.